# Fortran Type in Decleration

Tags: types, fortran

I have a custom type and I want to place a value in approximately the same place as where I am defining the custom type like I can with a standard type. I understand this isn't a clear description so I can define a value for MyInt and the first program will compile but the second one will not.

Thank you,

John

Will compile

```
program test
type :: MyType
    integer MyInt
end type MyType

integer :: MyInt = 2
type(MyType) :: a
a%MyInt = 3

write(*,*) a%MyInt, MyInt

end program test
```

Won't compile

```
program test
type :: MyType
    integer MyInt
end type MyType

type(MyType) :: a
a%MyInt = 3
integer :: MyInt = 2

write(*,*) a%MyInt, MyInt

end program test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment to Kyle, you asked how you can declare a new variable after initialising a variable of derived type. You can do that by initialising `a` on the same line you declare it. The syntax is:

```
type(MyType) :: a = MyType(3)
```

You can even initialise types with multiple components in the same way:

```
type NewType
    integer :: MyInt
    character(len=20) :: name
end type

type(NewType) :: b = NewType(7, "Foo")
```

The arguments to the type constructor are passed in the same order they are declared in the type specification, or with keyword arguments:

```
type(NewType) :: c = NewType(name="bar", MyInt=12)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of these two sequential lines:

```
a%MyInt = 3
integer :: MyInt = 2
```

You are trying to declare a new variable `MyInt` *after* you gave `a%MyInt` a value. Fortran requires you to put all the variable declarations **first** and later define the variables.

Comment: I know that, I was wondering if there was some way I could get around this restriction.